# MySQL not properly installed

Tags: mysql

I was updating 'mysql-server' with apt-get on the server of my employer last Saturday. Sadly, something went wrong and MySQL didn't install right. I heard that this happens sometimes with apt-get.

I followed some advice from Stackoverflow and some other stuff, but now I'm in even deeper.
After I uninstalled MySQL with dkpg, I reinstalled it with apt-get.
Apt-get says it's installed now, but I have no /etc/init.d/mysql(d) to start MySQL and the socket in /tmp/MySQL.sock isn't created.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as the site needs to go live asap, the original planning was last Thursday.

On a related question: I think I just removed the binaries with --purge, that's true, right? It would be quite a disaster if the databases were gone.

EDIT: With the help of some people at the data center, we got this fixed. Thanks for the help sledge.

Answer (score 0):

The databases are kept in /var/lib/mysql on debian based systems.  Check there to ensure that your databases still exist.

Which packages did you install?  You must install mysql-server in order to get the daemon.  Just mysql or mysql-client will not work.

Comment: I just checked that folder, and I still have the databases. I installed mysql-server.

Comment: Did it work?  You should have mysqld now.

Comment: No, that's the problem. I got some rc/ir's from dpkg -l | grep mysql, so I reinstalled those packaged. However, on installation of mysql-server-5.1, I get the error that /etc/init.d/mysql does not exist.

Comment: Then update your RC configuration to have it launch on startup.  rcconf is a good tool for that.

Comment: There is no mention of anything mysql related in rcconf

Comment: what if you try: aptitude reinstall mysql-server mysql-server-5.1

Comment: That gives errors about the non-existence of /etc/init.d/mysql